# Sales Report Shows incorrect Invoiced amount

Tags: magento-1.9, reports

I'm running sales reports within Magento and I see that last month I did (roughly) $12000 in sales total and $5100 invoiced. Although I'm aware that these numbers shouldn't completely match, I would assume that they should be roughly around the same total.

I also ran a report on completed sales totals on my PayPal merchant account and I have confirmed that the sales totals are (within a margin of error) around $12000.

Looking in the past months, I see that these numbers were closer and within $300-500 off which is more reasonable when you take into account the cancelled orders.

The issue started to happen in June and this happens to coincide with the date that I upgraded from Magento 1.7.2 CE to Magento 1.9.0.1.

Why are my invoiced total's incorrect?

Comment: are you marking sales as "completed"?

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer to my issue; I had to refresh the lifetime statistics rather then just "Last days statistics" which is set by default.

Go to Reports -> Refresh Statistics. Select all of the different statistics, then under the "Actions" drop down box, select "Refresh Lifetime Statistics"